# How to assign project into sub-projects in matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have using matplotlib for a very long time (but maybe without professional usage). One thing bored me a lot is that matplotlib offering many operations but I do not know where it returns. For example when we draw a curve we use "plt.plot(...)", after which we use plt.show(). But this is a function and what can we obtained(OOP sense). It seems all the operations are acted on one object. When our requirements become complex and complexes, we use more and more complicated functions and structures. And sometimes unexpected, operations to other figures will also have influence at this one.

I want to use matplotlib in this way:

No matter what we want, it is a 2D graph. The final graph can be separated into different submission. We draw each graph independently and finally combine them or put one on another. And also we can change the ratio of each part. This kind of combination is not something like subplot indexed by several integer, but by using, for instance, coordinate x,y.

Does this kind of general method exist? I know one way is to save all subfigures into arrays(RGB,...) and conduct operations to it. But this is somewhat too much.

Comment: With regard to the programming part (which is not your real question), `matplotlib`’s interface design is heavily distorted by the desire for Matlab-like interactive use.  It’s not fully supported, but I have had good success making [Canvas objects](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html) directly to avoid the stateful, implicit `plt` interface.

Comment: the stateful `plt` interface is 100% optional.

Comment: Matplotlib axes need to be created inside a figure. This is however not really a problem, since you may first define your layout and then plot to it using functions. Matplotlib provides a complete object-oriented interface, so you have all the options you need. You may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783425/arrange-plots-that-have-subplots-called-from-functions-on-grid-in-matplotlib) for an example. Inversely, if you want help here, please provide a [mcve] yourself and clearly describe the problem you have achieving your goal.

Comment: Thanks. According to the comments, I found and read the corresponding documents. The object I want is just axes, I think.